# Searching datatable for data

Tags: c#

Currently the if statement finds the "starting with" text in the column and gets the row. I was wondering: how am I able to check if the next character in the string is `[`? This for example with the `StartsWith` method

```
 foreach (DataRow r in queryDataTable.Rows)
            {
                if (r[0].ToString().StartsWith(queryString))
                {
                    dt.ImportRow(r);
                }
            }
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? I can't see a single "?"

Answer (score 1):

If your question is how to find all rows that have the first property starting with the querystring + the "[" then why not just append that char to the query string?

like this:

```
foreach (DataRow r in queryDataTable.Rows)
    {
        if (r[0].ToString().StartsWith(queryString + "["))
        {
            dt.ImportRow(r);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a regular expression:

```
foreach (DataRow r in queryDataTable.Rows)
{
    bool match = Regex.IsMatch(r[0].ToString(),".{1}\[.*",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);

    if (match) dt.ImportRow(r);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool PostConditionIsChar(DataRow dr, string query, char charToCheck)
{
  string firstCol = dr[0].ToString();
  return firstCol.StartsWith(query) ? firstCol.Replace(query, "").Length > 0 && firstCol.Replace(query, "").First() == charToCheck : false;
}
```

**Usage**

```
dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(row => PostConditionIsChar(row, queryString, '[')).ToList().ForEach(rowToAdd => dt.ImportRow(rowToAdd))
```

That should do it for you.

Comment: that's the *first* character, not the *next* character.

Comment: @MattEllen I see now... The question was made clearer since I started my answer :P

Comment: @MattEllen My edit should do it now.